# How to print packet info , source-ip, destination-ip, time, protocol of the packet (i.e. Icmp, arp, tcp, udp, dns etc.) using pyshark and python

Tags: python, tcp, protocols, arp, icmp

I want to print the details of the packets that is capture using pyshark. I want the details of the packet like info of packet, source-ip, destination-ip, protocol(like, unp, tcp, imp, arp, dns etc).

I use the code below.

```
import pyshark 
import time
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='eth0')
capture.sniff(timeout=5)
for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    protocol = packet.transport_layer
    src_addr = packet.ip.src
    src_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].srcport
    dst_addr = packet.ip.dst
    dst_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].dstport
    info = packet.info
    print (info, localtime,"\t",protocol,"\t", src_addr,"\t", src_port,"\t", dst_addr)
   # print (packet.show())
```

Comment: what's the issue with above code? You getting any errors?

Comment: I am not getting the packet info and as well as I am getting the below error sometime. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/help.py", line 46, in <module>
    src_port = packet[protocol].srcport
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyshark/packet/packet.py", line 50, in __getitem__
    if layer.layer_name == item.lower():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to include the error message this code generates, as well as any additional output.